# Pass value between visual webparts in sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

Am new to SharePoint but have better experience in asp.net web application development. I am using Visual Studio to development SharePoint application. 
I have created two visual webparts - 1. StudentPersonalDetails: to add personal details of students and 2. StudentCourseDetails: to add course details of the student.When save is clicked in StudentPersonalDetails it adds the data to a list - ListPersonalDetails. When save is clicked in StudentCourseDetails, it should add data to the list - ListCourseDetails. ListCouseDetails contains StudentID which is to be passed from StudentPersonalDetails to StudentCourseDetails.

How can i do this? Am using Visual Studio 2010 for application development. Is a practice in SharePoint 2010 to use session variables, viewstate variables or querystring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to do web part communication.  This functionality is available in SharePoint and you can see an example of doing this here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx

Also you can see this option on web parts by clicking on the edit menu and there is an option for connect to on the web part options.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links; may be helpful to you. It is better to move this question to sharepoint.stackexchange.com

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff623014.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2010/01/28/creating-a-sharepoint-visual-web-part-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFHQYQIMVPk

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2010/01/28/creating-a-sharepoint-visual-web-part-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx